# Stop asynchronous task AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am loading a video using AVPlayer lib using this code

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
NSArray *requestedKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kTracksKey, kPlayableKey, nil];
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler:^{        
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        Do things
```

If I enter this view and go back really fast the app crashes because I try to execute the code inside after releasing my objects that I use in it

Is there any way I could end this request to load values manually?

Comment: Hey did you got the solution? I am facing same issue too.

Comment: As it stands, it is not clear what task you were trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I ended up doing was keeping a boolean that shows to me if the page is still loaded.

On `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` I set `self.loaded = YES;`

and on `-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` I set `self.loaded = NO;`

So the first thing that I do on the code is to check this

```
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    NSArray *requestedKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kTracksKey, kPlayableKey, nil];
    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler:^{        
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (!self.loaded) return;
            Do things
```

Hope this helps you too!

Comment: You are allowed to answer you own questions! The information here is much more that should be included in a comment. I would just remove the @ mention and sorry line.